# Use get_nowait() in python without raising empty exception

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, queue, interprocess

I have an inter-process queue that is usually empty and only once in a while does something appear in it. In one of my threads I want to define a while loop like this:

```
def mythread(queue1):

    while (queue1.get_nowait() != 1):
        #do stuff
```

This works great until the queue is empty which happens quickly in my case. When the queue is empty calling get_nowait() or get(False) raises the empty queue exception. Is there any way to check the queue without blocking AND without raising the empty exception?

Comment: If you don't want to block, then something has to happen when you call it on an empty queue. Catch the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `empty` method

```
if queue1.empty():
   pass
else:
   # get items from the queue
```

Note: doc says "not reliable" (no kidding).

I suppose that's because it can return `True` (queue is empty) while a message is posted, so the operation is not as atomic as catching the exception. Well, followed by a `get_nowait()` call I suppose it doesn't matter unless some other thread can consume the queue as well, in which case a racing condition could occur and the queue could be empty when you try to read from it!

Comment: good idea, it looks like I need another while loop on top of the one I want

Comment: Using `pass` for nothing? So, why not `if not queue1.empty(): ...`?

Comment: it's a "positive" branch pattern, to materialize the fact that we do nothing when the queue is empty. But yes, you can use `not queue1.empty()`